# Why don't we define $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f$ in this case? (Improper Integrals)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Let $i\in\{1,2,\dots\}$.
Let $\delta_i:=i-\sqrt{i^2-\frac{1}{4i}}$.
Let $D_i:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid |x|\leq i,|y|\leq i\}-\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid |x|< i-\delta_i,|y|< i-\delta_i\}$.
Then, $\int_{D_i} 1=\frac{1}{i}$.
Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x):= 
\begin{cases}
(-1)^{i+1} & (\text{if }x \in D_i\text{ for some }i\in\{1,2,\dots\})\\
0 & (\text{if }x \notin \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i).
\end{cases}
$
Let $f_{+}$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{+}(x):=\max\{f(x),0\}$.
Let $f_{-}$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{-}(x):=\max\{-f(x),0\}$.
Let $C_i:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid |x|\leq i,|y|\leq i\}$
Then,
$\int_{C_i} f=1-\frac{1}{2}+\dots+(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{i}$,
So, $\lim_{i\to\infty}\int_{C_i} f=\log 2$.
But, $\lim_{i\to\infty}\int_{C_i} f_{+}=+\infty$.
But, $\lim_{i\to\infty}\int_{C_i} f_{-}=+\infty$.
So, we don't define $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f$.
I think it is natural to define $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f=\log 2$ in this case.
Why don't we define $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f$ in this case?

Comment: Maybe you should start by spelling out your definition of integrals $\int_{R} f(x)dx$ (and then its generalization to $\int_{R^n}$) for general functions and what properties do you want such integrals to have. Otherwise, the answer is "sure, define an integral any way you want and nobody can prove you wrong."

Comment: It's not Lebesgue integrable. But you could still define it as that limit if you want, you just have to be careful.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Mason Thank you very much for your information.